# Referring to `this` vue component within an event handler

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Given this Vue component that attaches a global event listener:

```
var app = new Vue({
    data: {
        foo: 0;
    },
    methods: {
        handle: function(e) {
            this.foo = 1; // this refers to handler, not app
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        window.addEventListener("keypress", this.handle);
    }
});
```

What is the correct way to refer to `this` from within the event handler in order to update the component state? Alternatively, is there a better way to set event handlers on the entire `window`?

Comment: Does [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572) apply to Vue?

Comment: actually `this` is binded to the vue instance

Comment: @Ifaruki I believe you are correct and that my assumption about `this` is plain wrong! If you add this as an answer I'll accept it since it is correct.

Comment: @YuvalAdam i dont unerstand the question because i have recreated this little app and it works fine

Comment: Did you try just like this mounted: function() { var ctx=this;
        window.addEventListener("keypress", ctx.handle);
    }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually `this` is binded to the vue instance and your code works fine.

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        foo: 0
    },
    methods: {
        handle: function(e) {
            this.foo++; 
            console.log(this.foo);
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        window.addEventListener("keypress", this.handle);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
{{ foo }}
</div>
```

The common mistake is if you have for example an function with an callback and you try to use `this` inside the callback, it will be `undefined`

```
    handle: function(e) {
        this.foo++; 
        setTimeout(function(){
           console.log(this.foo); //undefined
        })
        console.log(this.foo);
    }
```

You could either use arrow functions

```
    handle: function(e) {
        this.foo++; 
        setTimeout(() =>{
           console.log(this.foo);
        })
        console.log(this.foo);
    }
},
```

Or if its need to be backwards compatible you could use `.bind()`

```
    handle: function(e) {
        this.foo++; 
        setTimeout(function(){
           console.log(this.foo);
        }.bind(this))
        console.log(this.foo);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data property should be a function, not an object.

```
data(){
 return {
  foo: 1
 }
}
```

Comment: None of this is true. The example code is almost a direct copy from the Vue documentation, and as can be seen in the answer, apparently, works just fine.

Comment: What I said is all true. You literally changed the code :)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html somewhere in the page it is explained why data should be a function, just to finalize my point :), sure it wasn't the reason why it wasn't working, but in all that spaghetti code, I couldn't really see the big picture